# Accessing Viariable from Other PHP File

Tags: php

I'm still starting to learn PHP and i don't know which part did i miss why i can't access the variable from other php file even though i include this in my index file.

Here's how i include the other php into my index file

**index.php**

```php
<?php
    include 'includes/signup.inc.php';
?>
```

With in this `index.php` I have this form:

```php
<form id="form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
    <div id="form1">
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname"><span><?php echo $fnameerr?></span>
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

the variable `$fnameerr` is a variable from other php file inside includes folder named `signup.inc.php` if I only have this code inside `signup.inc.php`

```php
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$fname    = $lname = $email = $uid = $pw = "";
$fnameerr = $lnameerr = $emailerr = $uiderr = $pwerr = "";
```

this variable `$fnameerr` can be seen from `index.php`.  But when i start to include this code:

```php
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$fname = $lname = $email = $uid = $pw = "";
$fnameerr = $lnameerr = $emailerr = $uiderr = $pwerr = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    if (empty($_POST['fname']))
    {
        $fnameerr = "First Name Required";
    }
    else
    {
        $fname = cleandata($_POST['fname']);
    }
    if (empty($_POST['lname']))
    {
        $lnameerr = "Last Name Required";
    }
    else
    {
        $lname = cleandata($_POST['lname']);
    }
    if (empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $emailerr = "Email Required";
    }
    else
    {
        $email = cleandata($_POST['email']);
    }
    if (empty($_POST['uid']))
    {
        $uiderr = "User ID Required";
    }
    else
    {
        $uid = cleandata($_POST['uid']);
    }
    if (empty($_POST['pw']))
    {
        $pwerr = "Password Required";
    }
    else
    {
        $pw = cleandata($_POST['pw']);
    }
}

function cleandata($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if (!empty($fname) || !empty($lname) || !empty($email) || !empty($uid) || !empty($pw))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userlist(fname, lname, email, uid, pw) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uid', '$pw');";
}

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

I can't access my index.php instead i am redirected to dashboard.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Please don't use function `cleandata`. It is going to damage your data without doing anything helpful.

Comment: It looks like you found a very bad tutorial online. I strongly recommend to find a better tutorial and start over. It's difficult to say which part of it is wrong, because all of it is wrong.

Comment: Hi Dhaman, thanks for the comment, I got the tutorial from https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

But maybe I still have the very basic things in PHP since i didn't even get into half of its tutorial in PHP.  I'm not working into a specific project yet but i just want to understand why i can't access the variables in my signup.inc.php from my index.php

Comment: Please avoid w3schools.com They have very poor PHP tutorials. You are getting redirected because of `header("location:../index.php");` Remove this line and you will not be redirected.

Comment: Hi @Dharman, thank you so much for your time to comment on my question.  I got my question resolve.